# Missing Neovim RubyGem

Tags: rubygems, neovim

I've just installed neovim and I have problem with RubyGem.

Output of ':CheckHealth' indicates missing neovim RubyGem:

```
## Ruby provider
  - ERROR: Missing Neovim RubyGem
      - SUGGESTIONS:
        - Install or upgrade the neovim RubyGem using `gem install neovim`.
  - INFO: Ruby Version: ruby 2.2.6p396 (2016-11-15 revision 56800) [x86_64-linux]
  - INFO: Host Executable: not found
  - INFO: Host Version: not found
```

After installing 'sudo gem install neovim':

```
Successfully installed neovim-0.3.1
Parsing documentation for neovim-0.3.1
Done installing documentation for neovim after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

The output of ':CheckHealth' is the same as before:

```
## Ruby provider
  - ERROR: Missing Neovim RubyGem
      - SUGGESTIONS:
        - Install or upgrade the neovim RubyGem using `gem install neovim`.
  - INFO: Ruby Version: ruby 2.2.6p396 (2016-11-15 revision 56800) [x86_64-linux]
  - INFO: Host Executable: not found
  - INFO: Host Version: not found
```

Am I missing something? How can I fix this problem?

```
:echo has('ruby') returns 1
```

Thank you very much.

EDIT: 
Here is output of 'gem env'

```
RubyGems Environment:

  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.6.10
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.2.6 (2016-11-15 patchlevel 396) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.2.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/my_user_name/.gem/ruby/2.2.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby.ruby2.2
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/my_user_name/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.2.0
     - /home/my_user_name/.gem/ruby/2.2.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => true
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :benchmark => false
     - :install => "--format-executable --no-user-install"
     - "install" => "--format-executable --no-user-install"
     - :format_executable => true
     - :update => "--format-executable --no-user-install"
     - "update" => "--format-executable --no-user-install"
     - :sources => ["https://rubygems.org"]
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/my_user_name/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
     - /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are in linux install gem custom install and run with `sudo`

Comment: Yes, I'm in linux. I'm sorry but I don't quite understand what should I do.

What command should I write? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

see this can help you for set paths

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203376/how-to-set-ruby-gem-home-and-gem-path

and see this https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4405282

Comment: I've update my question with output of 'gem env'.

Executable directory is /usr/bin, which I already have in my PATH.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add the PATH of installed gems into your PATH.

You can do it like below in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` or other shells' rc/profile files.

`[ -d $HOME/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/bin ] && PATH=$HOME/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/bin:$PATH`

`export PATH` together with all other PATH values.

Just replied at https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/11336/missing-neovim-rubygem/12553#12553